# Disable HTTPS on Heroku Node.js/Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

After uploading to Heroku all the URLs are `https`. I would like them to be `http`. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both.

http://your-app.herokuapp.com
or
https://your-app.herokuapp.com

Heroku enabled SSL for all subdomains.

Comment: what if we want server to refuse http on heroku ?